# Grayed out cells Excel

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is described below.

I have drop-down list with two options: `X` and `Y` (Table number 1).
When I pick `X` in the table number 1, there should not be an option for the user to pick from the list process designation as presented in the table number 2.
When I pick `Y` in the table number 1, there should not be an option for the user to pick from the list `process1 type`, `process2 type`, `process3 type`, presented in the table number 3 (The OPT1 should correspond to `A`-`E`-`K` from Supportive table.

Those cells highlighted in gray should be not editable. The rest should be able to be freely modified.

Here is the sample [file](http://speedy.sh/a76sb/problem-1.xlsx).

I would like to solve it without VBA (if it's possible).

Comment: Hello. I have no idea how to implement this kind of solution. The problem for me is how to implement this solution for making this part not available to click for the user.

Comment: would you be happy to only implement the required formatting? i.e. grey the relevant boxes out. (but user could in theory still change them.)

Comment: It'a impossible to achieve without VBA - in my opinion.

Comment: Pity. And may you suggest by any chance how it's possible by using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

if you're happy with just formatting (and not locking cells), this can be done without VBA, using standard conditional formatting:

e.g. select cell B5, click conditional formatting/new rule/use a formula to determine which cells to format. for the formula enter `=$B$3="Y"` and choose the format you'd like to apply.

repeat variants for other cells.

if you wish to lock cells to stop user editing, you must use VBA. Place the below code in the worksheet code area. note  you'll have to right click/format cell/protection/locked to unlock the input cell so this can be changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("B3") = "X" Then

        ActiveSheet.Unprotect

        Range("B4").Locked = True
        Range("B4").Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128) 'no such thing as vbgGray

        Range("B5").Locked = False
        Range("B5").Interior.Color = vbYellow

        Range("B6").Locked = False
        Range("B6").Interior.Color = vbYellow

        Range("B7").Locked = False
        Range("B7").Interior.Color = vbYellow

        ActiveSheet.Protect

    ElseIf Range("B3") = "Y" Then

        ActiveSheet.Unprotect

        Range("B4").Locked = False
        Range("B4").Interior.Color = vbYellow

        Range("B5").Locked = True
        Range("B5").Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)

        Range("B6").Locked = True
        Range("B6").Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)

        Range("B7").Locked = True
        Range("B7").Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)

        ActiveSheet.Protect

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for it, but mostly I am struggling with dynamic drop-down list and dynamic disabling. But thanks anyway